# Squid Proxy always segments HTTP data into multiple frames

Tags: http, tcp, proxy, squid

I am using squid proxy server to route http calls to different applications based on src ip. 
Squid proxy always segments data coming from application and forming multiple frames. First frame contains HTTP headers and next frame contains actual content.

Is it possible to configure squid proxy to send the headers and content in the same frame?

[image]

As in Frame 13333 and 13334 should be sent as one frame.

Comment: Can you explain why you need this at all? Since TCP is a streaming protocol the reader should not make any assumptions what will be in a single read/recv but should read until it has all the data.

Comment: Because the other end is a legecy device and crashes each time such a combination of packets is sent.

Comment: I don't think squid can be configured to work around such bugs. You probably need to make the changes in the source code yourself or use some fixing proxy in between.

Comment: would you have any recomendation for a fixup proxy?
would varnish cache work ?

Comment: No, I have no idea. Since this is a very special case of working around some broken client don't expect anything ready made.